# Automating Azure Postgresql Restore

Tags: azure-postgresql

What I REALLY want to do is reset my postgresql db back to 4 hours prior (after my destructive DAST test runs), but I understand that is impossible, I can only restore to a NEW database.  So I'll settle for some way to 'automate' this:

- Restore 4 hour old point-in-time database from backup
- Delete initial database

Is there Azure-cli for this kind of thing? Any better way to do this in Azure?  I need to do this atomically, so I don't accidentally add multiple databases and incur large costs.  Any pointers would be greatly appreciated as I have never done this kind of thing, but I was really counting on being able to reset my database "back in time" and am very disappointed this isn't allowed. Please point me in the right direction and I'll try to google my way.

Comment: It is correct you can only restore to a new database from a backup taken at a specific point in time.

what do you meant by automatically do you mean using some custom jobs and running them on a schedule.